# Stopping/Purging Periodic Tasks in Django-Celery

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I have managed to get periodic tasks working in django-celery by subclassing PeriodicTask. I tried to create a test task and set it running doing something useless. It works.

Now I can't stop it. I've read the documentation and I cannot find out how to remove the task from the execution queue. I have tried using celeryctl and using the shell, but registry.tasks() is empty, so I can't see how to remove it.

I have seen suggestions that I should "revoke" it, but for this I appear to need a task id, and I can't see how I would find the task id.

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A task is a message, and a "periodic task" sends task messages at periodic intervals. Each of the tasks sent will have an unique id assigned to it.

`revoke` will only cancel a single task message.  To get the id for a task you have to keep
track of the id sent, but you can also specify a custom id when you send a task.

I'm not sure if you want to cancel a single task message, or if you want to stop the periodic task from sending more messages, so I'll list answers for both.

There is no built-in way to keep the id of a task sent with periodic tasks,
but you could set the id for each task to the name of the periodic task, that way
the id will refer to any task sent with the periodic task (usually the last one).
You can specify a custom id this way,

either with the `@periodic_task` decorator:

```
@periodic_task(options={"task_id": "my_periodic_task"})
def my_periodic_task():
    pass
```

or with the `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE` setting:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {name: {"task": task_name,
                              "options": {"task_id": name}}}
```

If you want to remove a periodic task you simply remove the `@periodic_task` from the codebase, or remove the entry from `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE`.
If you are using the Django database scheduler you have to remove the periodic task
from the Django Admin interface.

PS1: `revoke` doesn't stop a task that has already been started. It only cancels
tasks that haven't been started yet.  You can terminate a running task using
`revoke(task_id, terminate=True)`.  By default this will send the `TERM` signal to
the process, if you want to send another signal (e.g. KILL) use
`revoke(task_id, terminate=True, signal="KILL")`.

PS2: revoke is a remote control command so it is only supported by the RabbitMQ
and Redis broker transports.
If you want your task to support cancellation you should do so by storing a `cancelled`
flag in a database and have the task check that flag when it starts:

```
from celery.task import Task

class RevokeableTask(Task):
    """Task that can be revoked.

    Example usage:

        @task(base=RevokeableTask)
        def mytask():
            pass
    """

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if revoke_flag_set_in_db_for(self.request.id):
            return
        super(RevokeableTask, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you for this extremely thorough answer.

Answer (score 8):

Just in case this may help someone ...  We had the same problem at work, and despites some efforts to find some kind of management command to remove the periodic task, we could not. So here are some pointers.

You should probably first double-check which [scheduler class](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#using-custom-scheduler-classes) you're using.

> The default scheduler is `celery.beat.PersistentScheduler`, which is simply keeping track of the last run times in a local database file (a shelve).

In our case, we were using the [`djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler`](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/blob/master/djcelery/schedulers.py#L140) class.

> `django-celery` also ships with a scheduler that stores the schedule in the Django database

Although the documentation does mention a way to remove the periodic tasks:

> Using `django-celery`‘s scheduler you can add, modify and remove periodic tasks from the Django Admin.

We wanted to perform the removal programmatically, or via a (celery/management) command in a shell.

Since we could not find a command line, we used the django/python shell:

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> from djcelery.models import PeriodicTask
>>> pt = PeriodicTask.objects.get(name='the_task_name')
>>> pt.delete()
```

I hope this helps!