# How to remove all due tasks from celery scheduler DatabaseScheduler

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task, celerybeat

My `project` has a lot of pending tasks `task.com-43` to get executed on every `5` seconds. I want to remove all my pending tasks.

```
→ celery -A Project beat --loglevel=debug --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler
celery beat v4.2.1 (windowlicker) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
LocalTime -> 2018-12-30 08:44:30
Configuration ->
    . broker -> redis://localhost:6379//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> django_celery_beat.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler

    . logfile -> [stderr]@%DEBUG
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 seconds (5s)
[2018-12-30 08:44:30,310: DEBUG/MainProcess] Setting default socket timeout to 30
[2018-12-30 08:44:30,311: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
[2018-12-30 08:44:30,312: DEBUG/MainProcess] DatabaseScheduler: initial read
[2018-12-30 08:44:30,312: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2018-12-30 08:44:30,312: DEBUG/MainProcess] DatabaseScheduler: Fetching database schedule
[2018-12-30 08:44:30,348: DEBUG/MainProcess] Current schedule:
[2018-12-30 08:44:30,418: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task task5.com-43 (project_monitor_tasks)
[2018-12-30 08:44:30,438: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Synchronizing schedule...
[2018-12-30 08:44:30,438: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2018-12-30 08:44:30,455: DEBUG/MainProcess] project_monitor_tasks sent. id->d440432f-111d-4c96-ab4f-00923f4cf7e1
[2018-12-30 08:44:30,464: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 4.93 seconds.
[2018-12-30 08:44:35,413: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task task.com-43 (project_monitor_tasks)
[2018-12-30 08:44:35,414: DEBUG/MainProcess] project_monitor_tasks sent. id->ff0438ce-9fb9-4ab0-aa8a-8a7636c67d90
[2018-12-30 08:44:35,424: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 4.98 seconds.
[2018-12-30 08:44:40,419: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task task.com-43 (project_monitor_tasks)
[2018-12-30 08:44:40,420: DEBUG/MainProcess] project_monitor_tasks sent. id->d0022780-7d5f-4e7b-965e-9fda0d607cbe
[2018-12-30 08:44:40,431: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 4.98 seconds.
[2018-12-30 08:44:45,425: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task task.com-43 (project_monitor_tasks)
[2018-12-30 08:44:45,427: DEBUG/MainProcess] project_monitor_tasks sent. id->9b3eb775-60d5-4daa-a019-e0dfae932380
[2018-12-30 08:44:45,439: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 4.98 seconds.
....
....
```

I'm using Redis for the backend database for `Project` tasks, I Tried Purging The Celery & Flushing the redis but still, it is executing all pending tasks.

```
ps auxww | grep 'celery worker' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9 ## Stopping all workers first
celery -A project purge
redis-cli FLUSHALL
service redis-server restart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could remove all the tasks is by deleting the tasks from `Periodic Tasks Models` but first stop all your workers & purge all `project` tasks.

The answer to the question is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33047721/10372434